# Issue with references and NuGet packages after working on two different PC's on same project

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I posted earlier today. That issue was resolved but could possibly be related. I committed my work from the week last Friday. On Saturday I pulled that work at home on a different PC. After all my changes I committed and sync'd. Now on Monday I am having all kinds of reference issues.

My latest issue is with ExtendedXmlSerializer. I have been having issues where it can't seem to find libraries that it needs. I was getting the following:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. File name:
> 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
> ExtendedXmlSerializer.Configuration.ConfigurationContainer..ctor()

I uninstalled the NuGet package for ExtendedXMLSerializer. I then reinstalled ExtendedXMLSerializer. I now get a different error saying the same basic statement - It can't find something it is looking for to work.

I have been through this cycle multiple times now and every time I uninstall and reinstall ExtendedXMLSerializer I'll get a different error then before. I feel like I am playing "Whack-A-Mole".

I have tried saving and closing Visual Studio between uninstall and reinstall. I have tried removing unused references between uninstalling and reinstalling. I have tried cleaning the solution. I have manually deleted the bin folder. I have tried manually deleting the .vs folder. VS has recoginized that some of mu NuGet packages need fixing and I have allowed it to do so automatically. Nothing has helped.

It seems like I need to do a full rebuild of all references and packages needed. How can I get ExtendedXMLSerializer and whatever else back to where they need to be to get some actual programming done?

**Edit** - Contents of the csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{4CE3E01F-DBEA-42A0-AA49-0B6B81D51E6B}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Dispensing</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Dispensing</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EasyTree, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EasyTree.1.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\EasyTree.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ExtendedXmlSerializer, Version=3.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ExtendedXmlSerializer.3.7.5\lib\net452\ExtendedXmlSerializer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GeometRi, Version=1.3.5.16, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\GeometRi.1.3.5.16\lib\net20\GeometRi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="LightInject, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\LightInject.6.4.0\lib\net46\LightInject.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NReco.LambdaParser, Version=1.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50b5ad72a1d364c6, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NReco.LambdaParser.1.0.12\lib\net45\NReco.LambdaParser.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks, Version=28.1.0.74, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c4797c3e4eeac03, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.Interops.0.3.0\lib\net40\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SolidWorks.Interop.swconst, Version=28.1.0.74, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19f43e188e4269d8, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.Interops.0.3.0\lib\net40\SolidWorks.Interop.swconst.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished, Version=28.1.0.74, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89a97bdc5284e6d8, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.Interops.0.3.0\lib\net40\SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Collections.Immutable.5.0.0\lib\net461\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Interactive, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Interactive.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Interactive.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO" />
    <Reference Include="System.Linq.Expressions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="UnitsNet, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8601875a1f041da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\UnitsNet.4.102.0\lib\net47\UnitsNet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="Xarial.XCad, Version=0.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60dcaf351d4060db, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.0.7.6\lib\net461\Xarial.XCad.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks, Version=0.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60dcaf351d4060db, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.0.7.6\lib\net461\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xarial.XCad.Toolkit, Version=0.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60dcaf351d4060db, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xarial.XCad.Toolkit.0.7.6\lib\net461\Xarial.XCad.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Classes\DispenseEntityComparer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\DispenseEntity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\DispenseFile.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\Point.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\PersistentEntityData\EntityData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Options.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\SketchInventory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Utilities\InventoryBuilder.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Utilities\TagHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Units.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Utilities\Transformer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Utilities\VolumeSetter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DispenseExceptions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DocumentHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Enumerations\Enums.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extensions\DotNetExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extensions\NodeExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extensions\SolidWorksExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Extensions\XCadExtensions.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Factories\DispenseEntityFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Factories\PointFactory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IDispensingData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IPoint.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\ITransformable.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IVolumeDispensable.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\INonReversible.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IDispenseEntity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\IReversible.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Interfaces\INode.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PropertyPages\DispenseOptionSketchVolume.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PropertyPages\OptionsPageData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PropertyPages\SketchEntityVolumePage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="PropertyPages\SketchSettingsPageData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SharplineAddIn.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Classes\Utilities\ChainSorter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\Arc.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\Circle.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\Line.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\BlockInstance.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Classes\Entities\Sketch.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SwDocManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="VolumeUserControl.cs">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="VolumeUserControl.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>VolumeUserControl.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="ClassDiagram1.cd" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="VolumeUserControl.resx">
      <DependentUpon>VolumeUserControl.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.0.7.6\build\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.0.7.6\build\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.0.7.6\build\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.0.7.6\build\Xarial.XCad.SolidWorks.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: .NET core or .NET Framework? It would be helpful if you shared the .csproj you're trying to build.

Comment: .Net 4.8 class library

Comment: That explains a lot, unfortunately. .NET 4.8 has quite serious problems when it comes to resolving package dependencies, particularly if you are still using `packages.config` references. If possible, I suggest to upgrade to NET 5.0, this handles package dependencies (and particularly indirect dependencies) much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I did just see that there was an option on the NuGet package "Uninstall Options -> Remove Dependencies". This was unchecked. I checked it, uninstalled the ExtendedXMLSerilalizer package and reinistalled. It installed a lot more this time. I noticed that one of the packages it installed was "System.Collections.Immutable 1.7.1. Before I did this that version was 5.0.something. It now seems to be running OK.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and thanks for sharing the solution.